# Голосовой помощник не говорит, но ошибок не выводит

Tags: python, windows-11

Возникла проблема при переходе на *Windows 11*, мой голосовой помощник перестал говорить, ошибок никаких не выводит, все модули установлены!

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import os 
import sys 
import webbrowser  

def talk(words):      
    print('words')      
    os.system("say "+words)  
    talk("Привет, спроси что у меня что-либо")
```

Comment: а что в винде есть стандартный софт для вот этого?  os.system("say "+words)

Comment: Нет, просто я думаю что это связано с переустановкой системы